# New-AzADServicePrincipal Oauth2PermissionScope

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to create an Azure AD App with and SPN for web server authentication. Some of the powershell commands have been updated and I can't figure out how to add graph permissions to these. In the portal its look like below.

I've created a new SPN using `New-AzADServicePrincipal` but I also need to add the graph permission `User.Read` as below. I can't figure out how to do this, the link mentions hash tables but I can't understand the format.

[New-AzADServicePrincipal notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azadserviceprincipal?view=azps-7.2.0#notes)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer the following links:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/add-azadapppermission?view=azps-7.2.0#syntax
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference